# How to add stripslashes to get_option()

Tags: regex, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sublimetext, stripslashes

Hy, I created a WordPress Theme using a lot of custom options. While saving the options in the backend amongst other things I'm adding backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. Such as ' and ".

Now I need to remove them before displaying them on the frontend. The easiest way would be `stripslashes(get_option($key))`. But that would mean I'd have to go though the whole Theme and change all `get_option()` manually.

Is there a way to add a filter to the `get_option()`?

If not, is there a way to achieve this with find/replace (I'm using Sublime Text 3 which allows regex)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create your own function in place of `get_option()` (but which takes advantage of it)? For example, you could define the following in **functions.php**:

```
function my_stripslashes_function($option, $default = false) {
    return stripslashes( get_option($option, $default) );
}
```

And then use Sublime to replace all instances of `get_option` with `my_stripslashes_function`...no regex required, and it's more DRY.

Comment: Well, now I have to say I feel kind of stupid. That is of course a great solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Sublime Text you can realize it with an regex:

find: `get_option\((.[^)]*)\)`
replace with: `stripslashes(get_option($1))`

If you need to debug a regex yourself here is a helpful tool: https://regex101.com/r/rY7oG6/2

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
But now it selects quite a lot stuff I don't want to be selected. For example:
`if(get_option($id,'')==$o){$selected='selected';}` selects `get_option($id,'')==$o)` (But I just want `get_option($id,'')`)

Comment: Thanks! But now I have one more problem to deal with:
`if(get_option('the_key'.qtranxf_getLanguage(),'')=='hello'){`

Comment: hah I guess that won't work. The regex catches everything between `(` and the first `)`. I don't know any reqex to find the correct `)`. I guess you can`t solve that with a regex sorry.